# How do I save a SQLite database with the .db extension?

Tags: android, sqlite, file-management

Super beginner here.

I've created a SQLite database and I want to view it with the SQLiteManager plugin, but my database doesn't add the .db extension on my (virtual) device.  So far I've had to copy the file to my computer, change the extension, and push it back in order for the SQLiteManager icon to enable. Then I can see the database.

How can I avoid this run-around?

Also, someone mentioned I shouldn't rely on "/data/data/" to be the correct path. They suggested I use `Context.openOrCreateDatabase` or one of the `get*Path` or `get*Dir` methods. Could someone elaborate on these? The code I used is from a Youtube tutorial I saw.

Here's the code that defines the path:

```
try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/GradesDB.db";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if(!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: are you extending SQLiteOpenHelper to create your database? if so, you should be supplying a database name in your constructor, just append ".db" on the end of that name.

Comment: **"The code I used is from a Youtube tutorial I saw."** : Ouch! One thing to remember - *anybody* can make a video and post it to YouTube - it doesn't mean they have the slightest idea about what they're doing. That code is wrong in several ways. Never hard-code a file-system path (manufacturers of Android devices can choose to use a different directory structure). Also using `getBaseContext()` is something you'd rarely do unless you have a specific requirement (and know what the implications are).

Comment: Thanks, @panini! It was that simple to get the database to be accessible. And @Squonk, I'm trying to figure out why the tutorial included this block of code anyway. What exactly does it do and what's a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

You should not rely on "data/data" because it may change or it may not work on some devices, `getDatabasePath (String name)` will always return the correct path, the documentation says

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created with openOrCreateDatabase

Comment: Hey, I've done some reading on DB design and have improved my code's implementation. However, the one part I haven't fixed is my original post. I guess I'm confused as to what it actually does and what I should do instead. Is it creating the database if it doesn't already exist? I had a crash once after this code would have run on a fresh VM and the database file was never created.

Answer (score 1):

this is not the right way to work on data base on android
use this guide to create a dbhelper

[guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

and after this you can make the db file name whatever you like

Comment: you should avoid just linking to off-site resources, as they can be susceptible link rot. Its better to pull out the relevant information and add that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late

First at all use this dependency

```
    compile 'com.ajts.androidmads.sqliteimpex:library:1.0.0'
```

and use this code to export the database

```js
public static boolean exportDb(Context context, String databaseName) {

        File dbDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your_path");
        if (!dbDir.exists())
        {
            dbDir.mkdirs();
        }

        SQLiteImporterExporter sqLiteImporterExporter = new SQLiteImporterExporter(context, databaseName);
        try {
            sqLiteImporterExporter.exportDataBase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"your_path");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with I1nuxuser.  Here is another reference: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: you should avoid just linking to off-site resources, as they can be susceptible link rot. Its better to pull out the relevant information and add that in your answer.